# OpenGL 3.30 / GLSL 3.30 - MRT outputting black textures

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glew, glfw

I've been stuck with this problem for about four days now.  I'm trying to get my geometry to rendered into an FBO (G-buffer) with three textures (albedo, normal, depth).  So far, I've 'somewhat' implemented MRT functionality, but when I use gDEBugger to inspect the textures, they just appear black.  No matter what I change, they result in solid black.  The actual values outputted are correct, I checked by disabling MRT to make the fragment shader output to back buffer.  The textures are being initialized properly, gDEBugger properly displays the parameters I have put for them.  But they all just have a solid black (0, 0, 0, 255) fill.

There's hardly any elaborate information on MRTs for GLSL 3.30. I've relied entirely on answered questions here, along with the OpenGL/GLSL docs and tutorials across the web (outdated, but I updated the code).  I've probably spent a full day looking for a solution for this problem on Google.  If there's something wrong with the ordering of the code, or syntax, please point it out.  I don't even know if this implementation is correct anymore...

I'm using Visual C++ 2010, OpenGL 3.30 and GLSL 3.30 (as said in the title).  For my libraries, GLFW 3.0 is being used for the windows, input, and OpenGL context, and GLEW 1.10.0 for extensions.

Keep in mind that all of this code is taken from my wrapper class.  The ordering of the code is how it is all run at runtime (in other words, it's like as if I didn't have a wrapper class, and all of the code was in main ()).

**Initialization Stage**

```
// Initialize textures
glGenTextures (3, tex_ids);

glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ids[0]); // Diffuse
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, res.x, res.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ids[1]); // Normal
glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, res.x, res.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ids[2]); // Depth
glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, res.x, res.y, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);


// Initialize FBO
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ids[0]);
glFramebufferTexture2D ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
             GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
             GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
             tex_ids[0], 
             0 ); // diffuse

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ids[1]);
glFramebufferTexture2D ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
             GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, 
             GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
             tex_ids[1], 
             0 ); // normal

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_ids[2]);
glFramebufferTexture2D ( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
             GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, 
             GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
             tex_ids[2], 0 ); // depth
glBindFramebuffer (GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Initialize shaders

// Snipped out irrelevant code relating to getting shader source & compiling shaders
glBindFragDataLocation (renderer_1prog, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, "diffuse_out");
glBindFragDataLocation (renderer_1prog, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, "normal_out");
glBindFragDataLocation (renderer_1prog, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, "depth_out");
// More snipped out code relating to linking programs and finalizing
```

**Draw Stage** - called on every frame

```
// Bind everything
glUseProgram (renderer_1prog);
glBindFramebuffer (GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_id);
GLenum targ [3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT };
glDrawBuffers (3, targ);

// Draw mesh
glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);

teshmesh.draw ();

// Unbind fbo
glDisable (GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glBindFramebuffer (GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer (GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0)in vec4 v;
layout(location = 1)in vec3 c;
layout(location = 2)in vec3 n;
out vec4 pos;
out vec3 col;
out vec3 nrm;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 world;
void main () {
    gl_Position = projection * view * world * v;
    pos = view * world * v;
    pos.z = -pos.z / 500.0;
    col = c.xyz;
    nrm = n;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330
in vec3 col;
in vec3 nrm;
in vec4 pos;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 diffuse_out;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 normal_out;
layout(location = 2) out vec3 depth_out;
out vec3 o;
void main () {
    diffuse_out = col;
    normal_out = (nrm / 2.0) + 0.5;
    depth_out = vec3 (pos.z, pos.z, pos.z);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you using ARB_debug_output to see the errors OpenGL emits in real time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here. Starting with the smallest:

```
glBindFragDataLocation (renderer_1prog, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, "diffuse_out");
glBindFragDataLocation (renderer_1prog, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, "normal_out");
glBindFragDataLocation (renderer_1prog, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, "depth_out");
```

These are pointless. You used `layout(location)` syntax in your shader to specify this, and [that takes priority over OpenGL-provided location settings](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers).

Also, these are *wrong*. You don't put the FBO buffer attachment name into the location; you put an *index* into the location. So even if you didn't use `layout(location)`, this is simply incorrect. [`glBindFragDataLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindFragDataLocation) will emit an OpenGL error, since the location will most assuredly be larger than `GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS​`.

Considering how many OpenGL errors your code should emit, I'm rather surprised that your use of gDEBugger didn't tell you about any of these.

---

```
glTexImage2D  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, res.x, res.y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

`GL_RGB8` is not one of the [required image formats for render targets](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Required_formats). Therefore, the implementation is not required to support it; it may but it doesn't have to. And since you never bothered to [check the completeness of the FBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness) (FYI: you should *always* do that), you didn't test that this combination of formats is valid.

Never render to a 3-component image. Pick 4, 2, or 1 instead.

---

```
GLenum targ [3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT };
glDrawBuffers (3, targ);
```

This is probably your main problem: your [`glDrawBuffers` call fails](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawBuffers). `glDrawBuffers` [sets the *color buffer outputs*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers). The depth buffer is not a color buffer. There's only one depth buffer, so there's no need to set it.

To write to the depth buffer... well, you shouldn't be writing a user-calculated value to the depth buffer. Just let the regular depth buffer writing handle it. But if you want to (and let me remind you again, you do not), you write to `gl_FragDepth`. That's what it's for.

Comment: I need a user-defined depth map because I'm going to be using fragment depths outside of the fragment the shader is working with. Anyways, I fixed and removed the offending code, and it works properly. Although, I noticed that some geometry was showing up in front of others incorrectly, so I needed depth testing.  Unfortunately, when I attach a renderbuffer to the FBO, all of the textures now turn white (the depth texture is red, because GL_R16). The only code I added is the renderbuffer generation/binding calls. gDEBugger doesn't say anything, and FBO status seems to be okay. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JarrodB: "*I need a user-defined depth map because...*" That doesn't explain why you have to *write* a user-defined *value* to the depth buffer, instead of letting the rasterizer-generated depth pass. That's probably why your depth is being screwed up; because you're screwing up your depth.

Comment: Well, I don't see how writing the user-defined value to a color buffer would affect the actual depth testing.

Comment: @JarrodB: OK, I can't see your newly revised code, so I don't know what you're writing or not writing to the depth buffer. But if it's like the above, then you aren't changing the normal value written to the depth buffer.

Comment: So somewhere in the fragment shader I have to write to gl_FragDepth? Normally, this would just be the gl_FragCoord.z, right?

Comment: @JarrodB: No, I'm saying you *shouldn't* be writing to that unless you want to modify the depth of the fragment. I'm saying that I can't know what's wrong with your new code because I *can't see it*. If you are having a problem with your new code, you should ask a new question about it.